# Binding Delay and Command CanExecute

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I have a fairly standard WPF app with a WPF Ribbon. In said Ribbon, I expose some buttons which bind to a combination of `RelayCommands` on my ViewModels and `RoutedUICommands` (ApplicationCommands).

As far as I understand it, WPF requeries the CanExcecute method of my commands whenever an input event (mouse click, key press) occurs on the `Window`.

Now, I order to improve performance when typing, I want to use the `Delay` property on my `Bindings`.

This is where I begin to see my problem. Imagine the following scenario:

I have a Command where CanExecute returns true based on the following condition:

```
Text.Length % 2 == 0;
```

So imagine here that Text is a property on my `ViewModel`.

The breakdown as I see it is this:

1. I type a character into the TextBox
2. The CanExecute method is called and UI state updated
3. After the delay (let's assume 300ms), the `Text` property on my `ViewModel` is updated.

How do I ensure that the CanExecute logic is called after the delay, not before?
Is there an incorrect assumption somewhere? I can't seem to find others with the same problem, which strikes me as odd.

I could call [InvalidateRequerySuggested](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but I don't see a good place to do so. Certainly not in my `ViewModels`.

**EDIT - UPDATED WITH EXAMPLE**

Here is my complete code to reproduce the issue:

View:

```
<Window x:Class="DelayBindings.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:delayBindings="clr-namespace:DelayBindings"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <delayBindings:MainWindowViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Delay=200}"/>

        <Button Command="{Binding MyCommand}">MyCommand</Button>
        <TextBlock>Count:</TextBlock>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text.Length}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private RelayCommand _myCommand;
    private string _text;

    public RelayCommand MyCommand
    {
        get { return _myCommand ?? (_myCommand = new RelayCommand(MyCommandExecuted, MyCommandCanExecute)); }
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set
        {
            _text = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Text"));
            }
        }
    }

    public void MyCommandExecuted()
    {

    }

    public bool MyCommandCanExecute()
    {
        return Text != null && Text.Length % 2 == 0;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Setting a Delay of 200ms will effectively reverse the logic of the button in most cases.

Please note that I would like to find a general solution to this problem as there are thousands of commands in our application.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you need to have a delay? You could override the `CanExecuteChanged` method with `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` described in the **CanExecute and CanExecuteChanged for routed commands** section in [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mikehillberg/archive/2009/03/20/icommand-is-like-a-chocolate-cake.aspx) article.

Comment: @MikeEason: Purely performance reasons. It is a rather large and enterprisey application with a lot of fields that get updated as you type in the text. (NotifyPropertyChanged events forcing redraws etc.). I will have a look at the article you mentioned, thanks.

Comment: Oh, well in that case, then I'd avoid the `CommandManager.RequerySuggested` option as this forces the `CanExecute()` method to be called every time the property is changed.

Comment: @MikeEason: The CanExecute will be called every time I type. That is not the problem as the metods for this are deliberately fast. The issue is that the CanExecute logic is triggered before the binding, therefore having buttons enabled that should not be and vice versa. Basically, I want to requery the commands only after the bindings have updated. But I can live with doing it in both cases.

Comment: Have you looked at Reactive Extensions (Rx)? The "hands on lab" PDF contains a sample where a textbox's TextChanged event is "throttled" (in their example, it calls some "auto-suggest" logic every X ms). It could be adapted to do what you want, but I suspect you'd have to sacrifice MVVM binding, and instead handle the Rx throttling in code-behind, which would update the VM's "Text" property (or whatever the CanExecute logic is based on).

Comment: @AndrewStephens: No, I haven't look at Rx yet. I will certainly do so now. Thanks for the tip.